# how to handle array.map inside a map operator of rxjs in angular

Tags: angular6

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import { map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import { Entity } from '../models/Entity';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class RestService<T> {

  constructor(protected http: HttpClient) { }
  abstract getUri(): string;
  abstract getInstance(): Entity;
  getAll(): Observable<Entity[]> {
    return this.http.get<Entity[]>(`${this.getUri()}`).pipe(map(response => response.map(item => { return this.getInstance().deserialize(item) })));
  }
}
```

I am writing the above code for deserializing my JSON response and I am getting the following error:

> core.js:1542 ERROR TypeError: response.map is not a function
>           at MapSubscriber.project (rest.service.ts:20)
>           at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:35)
>           at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>           at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/map.js.MapSubscriber._next
>   (map.js:41)
>           at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>           at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/filter.js.FilterSubscriber._next
>   (filter.js:38)
>           at FilterSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)
>           at MergeMapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/mergeMap.js.MergeMapSubscriber.notifyNext
>   (mergeMap.js:79)
>           at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/InnerSubscriber.js.InnerSubscriber._next
>   (InnerSubscriber.js:15)
>           at InnerSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next
>   (Subscriber.js:54)

I couldn't find a solution to this error. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Are you sure about the shape of the response?

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question? can you please repeat it .. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do that. In your code, response is not an array or at least the code doesn't understand if it's an array or what! So, you have to strongly type it if you are sure that the response will be of type `Entity[]`. Otherwise you can always type it as `any[]` and still `response.map()` will work.

```
  getAll(): Observable<Entity[]> {
    return this.http.get<Entity[]>(`${this.getUri()}`).pipe(
       map((response: Entity[]) => {
         response.map(item: Entity => { 
            return this.getInstance().deserialize(item) 
         })
       }
    ));
  }
```

Hope it helped. :)